# Retrieve a list of videos uploaded by a particular user via Facebook APIs?

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api

Let's say I have an app that let's a Facebook user make a collage.  In order to let users select which of their photos to add to their collage, I just grab a list of their albums like this:

```
$facebook->api('/me/albums/');
```

Then I can loop through that, getting the photos from each album.  Swell.  I want to let them add videos to their collage, too, so I try this:

```
$facebook->api('/me/videos/');
```

But that's incorrect — like `/me/photos/`, `/me/videos/` grabs media that the user has been **tagged in**, not media that the user *uploaded*.

Does anyone out there know how I can retrieve a list of videos that Facebook user has uploaded?  Some video equivalent of albums?  I haven't found anything in either the new Graph API nor in the old REST api.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `'/me/videos/uploaded'`. For a list of URLs available, check out the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) page on Facebook.

Comment: Can't believe I somehow missed that line of the documentation!  Thanks so much for pointing out!

Comment: it also show deleted video also. how can remove delete video from list?